# How to programmatically ungroup CSS selectors?

Tags: css, vim, css-selectors

I'd like to have an ungrouped selector view of a spaghetti CSS file. This means separating each grouped selector into its own line and duplicating the ruleset. Turns out none of csstidy-based or other custom online formatters seem to offer this. Perhaps someone here knows of a hidden command line tool gem or something for vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[csstidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/usage.php) can do it with `--merge_selectors=1`.

This csstidy-based online formatter exposes the functionality: http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Set "Regroup selectors" to "Only seperate selectors (split at ,)".

Comment: Hey, you're right, it can. Thank you very much. This seems to imply that csstidy *does* in fact support this operation or they have custom-patched it. EDIT merge_selectors=1

Comment: It looks like csstidy does in fact support this option: http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/merge_selectors.php

Comment: It's actually merge_selectors=1, the webpage doesn't mirror the command line option numbers which are 0|1|2.

Comment: I think part of the reason why I had trouble discovering this earlier is that merge_selectors=1 actually crashes csstidy on certain output on this 64-bit CentOS VPS. Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00000032f507acbb in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6. Seems to work fine on a pure 32-bit install.. Solution is probably https://github.com/Cerdic/CSSTidy